# High-Z RF amplifier for magloop RX vs Q-factor

Tags: antenna, antenna-construction, amplifier, magnetic-loop

I've noticed that increasing load on magloop reduces it's Q-factor, it becomes less selective.
Traditional way to approach this is reducing size of pickup loop, or alternatively, using transformer.

But is it possible/known approach to build FET high-Z preamp, which is connected to pickup loop?
Being high-Z it should allow to reach maximum possible selectivity for magloop, as only minimal current will flow due to capacitance of the gate. One might even make it resonant.

I understand that high-Z would not be impedance-matched to 50-Ohm, but in this case it's not the goal. Goal is to let main loop oscillate with high-Q. This will increase field strength, and might allow good reception even with mismatched pickup loop.

**Magloop example:** This one is from KR1ST, but mine is similar. Depending on size of the small, low-Z coupling loop - looses in main loop increase and it becomes less selective.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *oscillate*? And on my old low-Z magnetic loop, I used a separate coupling loop and a low-Z preamp. Can you please edit your question and insert a picture or drawing of your magloop?

Comment: @MikeWaters I updated the question. I am also using separate coupling loop, and noticed that when coupling loop is larger - system becomes less selective.

Answer (score 4):

Certainly it is possible to build a high-impedance amplifier. If you resonate the loop with a parallel capacitor (which perhaps includes the input capacitance of the amplifier), you've made a [parallel LC circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit#Parallel_circuit) which at resonance has minimum current and maximum voltage. A high-impedance amplifier is what you'd want to best extract that signal.

But if your objective is to use the loop on a wide frequency range without retuning, this is the opposite of what you want. Instead, you want a low-impedance amplifier, the lower the better. You can think of the loop as a current source by Faraday's law of induction. The lower the input impedance of the amplifier, less impedance to this current. [LZ1AQ has an example of such an amplifier](https://www.lz1aq.signacor.com/docs/wsml/wideband-active-sm-loop-antenna.htm):

[image]

In this design there is a passive filter at the input to attenuate the AM broadcast band and avoid overloading the amplifier. The low input impedance is achieved through the [common-base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_base) Q3 and Q4, then Q1 and Q2 further buffer the signal and are designed to drive a twisted pair.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer! I am focused on tunable, high-Q resonant loop, it will require re-tuning on any frequency change, but hopefully will offer superior filtering of out-of-band signals.

Comment: @BarsMonster selectivity of modern receivers is so good, there's nothing to be gained from a high-Q loop. So unless you're building an ultra-simple crystal set or something like that, I would not expect any measurable performance improvement from a loop -- just a lot of inconvenience in tuning it.

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II Unless he is using to to null out local RFI.

Comment: @MikeWaters with the directivity of the loop? Does the directivity change significantly with Q? For that matter, is the directivity of a loop substantially different from that of a dipole?

Comment: I'm not certain, Phil. But of course it's easier to rotate a small loop than a dipole. :-) The null on mine was perfect for nulling out a local ham on 75m while I was on 80m CW. (Receiver was a Collins 75S-3). It was a 3' diameter 1/2" aluminum hardline. It's Q must have been low, since I had no vacuum variables or wide copper straps; but the air variable was a 2-section unit wired so that it did not use the contact wipers, IIRC.

Comment: @BarsMonster [Phil is right about modern receivers](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/17986/high-z-rf-amplifier-for-magloop-rx-vs-q-factor/17989#comment31181_17989). What receiver are you using? And note that a simple resistive attenuator is much simpler (I use a 2k pot) than what you propose here, if all you need to do is prevent front-end overload from out-of-band signals.

Comment: @MikeWaters I am using SDR receivers: rspdx (it has some band filters, and tracking filter - but as far as I understand filtering performance is less than on high-end transcievers). Redpitaya SDRlab 122-16 - has no filters at all, it expects me to do all the filtering for more customized solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to purchase rather than build your own, high-input impedance preamps from [Hi-Z Antennas](https://www.hizantennas.com/high_impedance_amps.htm) sold by [DX Engineering](https://www.dxengineering.com/search?keyword=hi-z&SortBy=BestKeywordMatch&SortOrder=Ascending) may work for you. Because they are often used to drive multi-element phased array systems at long wavelengths, they are designed to work with inexpensive 75-ohm coax, but should work fine with 50-ohm cable in your application.

Two bullet points from the manual may be important considerations for use with a small receiving loop:

- The amplifier input Resistance is approximately 54KOhms in parallel with 12 Picofarads
- The Antenna Ground input terminal is AC coupled to eliminate any ground related DC current

Many other features that you might value. I have no affiliation with Hi-Z Antennas or with DX Engineering.

Answer (score 2):

John Kaufmann, W1FV, published a two-part article in the [September/October](https://www.pi4cc.nl/tech-info/rx-array/images/NJC-1) and [November/December 2011](https://www.pi4cc.nl/tech-info/rx-array/images/NJC-2) issues of the ARRL's *National Contest Journal* titled, "A Compact Dual-Band, 9 Circle Receiving Array." The phased-array system uses a simple amplifier with high input impedance:

[image]

The AD8055 op amp has a gain-bandwidth product of 300-MHz, so there's only about 10-dB of gain on the 10-meter band. Note that this "amplifier" is meant primarily to provide a wideband match between an electrically short antenna and a feedline. Its overall gain, as evidenced by the two 470-ohm resistors on the op amp inputs, is close to 0-dB.